# Show one single post after click on laravel 8 jetstream with livewire 2.0

Tags: laravel, mount

I’m using laravel 8 jetstream with livewire. I have a posts component with show a list of posts, I would like that on click to open a new page with only that post . I have mount() the id of that post and create a route for it but it not working. can someone post a simple example I have follow the following tutorial
http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-livewire-crud-with-jetstream-tailwind-cssexample.html

Comment: Read the documentation https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components

Comment: class ShowPost extends Component
{
    public $post;

    public function mount($id)
    {
        $this->post = Post::find($id);
    }  BUT HOW TO WRITE THE RENDER ?????

Answer (score 0):

To render components in Livewire you need to define a `render` method within your Livewire component. In that method, you specify which view to the component will render with an array as the second parameter to the `view()` function. More info here: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#render-method

```php
public function mount ($id)
{
    $this->post = Post::find($id);
}

public function render()
{
    return view('path.to.view', [
        'post' => $this->post,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: True but the fact is that the $id is in the mount($id) and not accessible ?

Comment: You have to manually set it to a property in your class if you’re not using route model binding. See updated answer.